# Apache poi all column does not fit in one page

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-poi

I am creating an excel sheet which contains some 12+ columns with different width. I need to fit all the column in one page when the **PageLayoutview** is selected. However when open the excel sheet in **PageLayoutview** mode those columns split into a second page but after switching to pageview mode (selecting **NormalView** mode then again select **PageLayoutview** mode) those columns fit in a single page.

```
    sheet.setAutobreaks(true);
    sheet.setFitToPage(true);
    sheet.setDisplayGridlines(false);
    /*page-layout-setting!!*/
    PrintSetup printSetup = sheet.getPrintSetup();
    printSetup.setFitWidth((short)1);
    printSetup.setFitHeight((short)0);
    printSetup.setLandscape(true);
    printSetup.setPaperSize(PrintSetup.A4_PAPERSIZE);
```

This is the print setup for my code.